# How can I add two annotations in mapview using swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

```
 let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 76.0100
 let longitude:CLLocationDegrees =25.3620


 let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

 let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 1
 let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 1
 let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

 let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

 mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

 let annotation:MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "Office ."
    annotation.subtitle = "My Office"

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


    print("Locations = \(locations)")

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    //var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate
    //var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = -121.934048
    //var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

    let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation.coordinate, span)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

I have created one annotation for one location. Now I need to create one more annotation for another location and show it in the map. How can I show that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a custom class as "**MyAnnotation**"

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MyAnnotation: NSObject,MKAnnotation {

    var title : String?
var subTit : String?
var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D

init(title:String,coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D,subtitle:String){

    self.title = title;
    self.coordinate = coordinate;
    self.subTit = subtitle;

}

}
```

add below code in your **viewdidload of viewcontroller** :-

```
        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 76.0100
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = 25.3620

        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

        //Second Location lat and long
        let latitudeSec:CLLocationDegrees = 75.0100
        let longitudeSec:CLLocationDegrees = 24.3620

        let locationSec:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudeSec, longitudeSec)

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1)

        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


        let myAn1 = MyAnnotation(title: "Office", coordinate: location, subtitle: "MyOffice");

        let myAn2 = MyAnnotation(title: "Office 1", coordinate: locationSec, subtitle: "MyOffice 1");

        mapView.addAnnotation(myAn1);
        mapView.addAnnotation(myAn2);
        //Instead of writing two lines of annotation we can use addAnnotations() to add.
```

Instead of this you can do with for loop also.

[image: Output of code]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am not getting it. Could you please provide me the full code? @Er.Shreyansh Sha. As I am new to swift  I am facing difficulty in understanding the code.

Comment: Thank you so much.. @Er.Shreyansh Shah

Comment: @RakeshMohan :- Accept and +1, if above answer is working for you.

Comment: I have used the same code provided above but still it shows only one annotations.

Comment: Dear.. Do zoomin/zoomout to mapview. in simulatior use cmd+altr key to zoomin/zoomout

Comment: Thank you so much @Er.Shreyansh Shah

Answer (score 0):

No need for a custom class. Just loop through the locations to create an annotation for each location.
Assuming Locations hold CLLocations and cityNames hold city names and myMap is the map (UI).

```
var counter = 0
var allLocations = [MKPointAnnotation]()
for location in Locations {
    let loc = MKPointAnnotation()
    loc.title = cityNames[counter]
    loc.subtitle = String(counter + 1)
    loc.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
                                            longitude: location.coordinate.longitude);
    allLocations.append(loc)
    counter += 1 
}
// show annotations
myMap.addAnnotations(allLocations as [MKAnnotation])
myMap.showAnnotations(myMap.annotations, animated: true)
```